# How to Route Elastic Beanstalk traffic through a Single IP for External API

Tags: amazon-web-services, nat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have Application deployed on Elastic Beanstalk and it need to make call to an external API Server which can reply to only single IP. AutoScaling is in picture. So I need to Route all my OUTBOND traffic through a Single Server. So that External API thinks that Request is coming from a single IP.
May be by using NAT or any Proxy Server or VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a NAT server to direct all traffic via one host. 
The instructions to setup a NAT server [are here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html).
Basically you launch a special AMI, setup routing and you're done.
Going this way, it's advisable to push your elastic beanstalk servers into a VPC. This way you'll gain some more security out of this move.